# Jenkins build not able to access global credentials(secret file)

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I want to use a secret file as build environment in a Jenkins job. But, whenever I am building the job it is throwing the below exception:

```java
FATAL: hudson.model.queue.Tasks.getAuthenticationOf(Lhudson/model/Queue$Task;)Lorg/acegisecurity/Authentication;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.model.queue.Tasks.getAuthenticationOf(Lhudson/model/Queue$Task;)Lorg/acegisecurity/Authentication;
at com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.getDefaultAuthenticationOf(CredentialsProvider.java:583)
at com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.findCredentialById(CredentialsProvider.java:654)
at com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.findCredentialById(CredentialsProvider.java:608)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.MultiBinding.getCredentials(MultiBinding.java:122)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.FileBinding.bindSingle(FileBinding.java:52)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.Binding.bind(Binding.java:126)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.SecretBuildWrapper.setUp(SecretBuildWrapper.java:58)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:154)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:586)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1593)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:247)
```

To achieve this I have installed "Credentials Binding plugin" along with all the dependent plugins and have configured the details of the secret file in global credentials section of Jenkins.

Note: If I deselect this option (**Use secret text(s) or file(s)**) the job is building fine.
Is there anything I am missing to read the file (global credential) or how can I read this file?

Comment: Did you ever have any luck here?  Having same issue.

Comment: Same issue with Jenkins 2.302 - pipeline trying to retrieve a secret file :  withCredentials([file(credentialsId: projectCredentialID, variable: 'AuthFile')]){ ....}